# Getting the key of an array using the value

Tags: php, arrays

Take for example the following array.

```
$example = array("India", "Canada", "America");
```

I have the value 'India' in my hand. I need to return the key of it that is 0 in this case. So how do I do this ? Please help me out.

Answer (score 6):

Sure, you can do with:

```
$key = array_search('India', $example); 
echo $key;
```

Also, you can build a function to find the numeric index of a key in an array:

```
function array_key_index($arr, $key) {
    $i = 0;
    foreach(array_keys($arr) as $k) {
        if($k == $key) return $i;
        $i++;
    }
}
```

For more information take a look http://php.net/manual/function.array-search.php

Comment: I saw that you are the fastest :)

Comment: I don't think I bother typing in an answer as you lot have beaten to it.

Comment: @EdHeal: It isn't about being fastest, it is about who stumbles upon a question first which he did :)

Comment: @Sarfraz if you feel this answer best meets your answer please select it as the correct answer :) –

Comment: @JavierMartinez: I have not asked this question

Comment: Sorry, my mistake i wanted to mean @Srivathsan hehehe

Comment: What is the "numeric index of a key"? Can you provide a use case where that could be useful?

Comment: It would return 0 for India, 1 for Canada or 2 for America

Comment: Javier, what I mean is that array_key_index will give meaningless results for `$arr = array(5 => 1, 8 => 2, 42 => 3)`, and arguably even meaningless results for `$arr = array('a' => 1, 5 => 2, 'dog' => 3)`

Comment: Oh ok, you are. In case it won't useful. Anyway, I think that could be good for @Srivathsan question :)

Answer (score 4):

Use [`array_search`](http://php.net/array_search):

```
$example = array("India", "Canada", "America");
$key = array_search('India', $example);
echo $key; // outputs 0
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `array_search`

```
$key = array_search('India', $example); // returns 0
```

See the manual for more details: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php

Answer (score 2):

A proper look into the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php) would have revealed [`array_search`](http://php.net/array_search)...

Answer (score 2):

array_search() is your friend .